# Java Date month difference

Tags: java, date

I have start date and end date.

I need the number of months between this two dates in Java.

For example

- From date: 2009-01-29
- To date: 2009-02-02

It has one jan date and one Feb date.

It should return 2.

Answer (score 43):

As the rest say, if there's a library that will give you time differences in months, and you can use it, then you might as well.

Otherwise, if `y1` and `m1` are the year and month of the first date, and `y2` and `m2` are the year and month of the second, then the value you want is:

```
(y2 - y1) * 12 + (m2 - m1) + 1;
```

Note that the middle term, (m2 - m1), might be negative even though the second date is after the first one, but that's fine.

It doesn't matter whether months are taken with January=0 or January=1, and it doesn't matter whether years are AD, years since 1900, or whatever, as long as both dates are using the same basis. So for example don't mix AD and BC dates, since there wasn't a year 0 and hence BC is offset by 1 from AD.

You'd get `y1` etc. either from the dates directly if they're supplied to you in a suitable form, or using a Calendar.

Comment: Simple & great solution) without any 3-party libraries

Answer (score 36):

Apart from using Joda time which seems to be the the favorite suggestion I'd offer the following snippet:

```
public static final int getMonthsDifference(Date date1, Date date2) {
    int m1 = date1.getYear() * 12 + date1.getMonth();
    int m2 = date2.getYear() * 12 + date2.getMonth();
    return m2 - m1 + 1;
}
```

**EDIT:** Since Java 8, there is a more standard way of calculating same difference. See my alternative answer [using JSR-310 api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811261/1712) instead.

Comment: Do you mean [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? [Yoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda) time was a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away.

Comment: The + 1 on the end in the return is unnecessary.  e.g. Mar 3, 2014, Mar 3, 2014 Would return a difference of 1 (when they are the same date they should return 0).  I wrote some unit tests, see my code below.

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. This will return a number of months included in the given date range. In your example, the range contains exactly one month.

Comment: Further, if you read the OP question correctly, this is exactly what was asked.

Comment: @Roland - Ah thanks for clarifying, I jumped to conclusions as to what the OP wanted.

Comment: evene easier with 1 code line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074578/4211173

Comment: Sure, but this is essentially the same answer. Removing line breaks does not necessarily improve readability!

Answer (score 30):

I would *strongly* recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (and as of Java 8, the Java Time apis) for this.

1. It makes this sort of work very easy (check out [Periods](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html))
2. It doesn't suffer from the threading issues plaguing the current date/time objects (I'm thinking of formatters, particularly)
3. It's the basis of the new Java date/time APIs to come with Java 7 (so you're learning something that will become standard)

Note also Nick Holt's comments below re. daylight savings changes.

Comment: If you can use Joda for any date related code.  I'd add number 4.  Joda is aware of the various changes that have occurred to datetime standards over the years, which its calculations take into account (particularly useful in Europe where daylight saving has been messed with over the years).

Comment: Joda is really good, so far is the best Date package I ever used, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Actually, the new [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is coming with Java 8 in 2014 (not Java 7 as stated above). Java 8 is in preview release now.

Comment: @NickHolt While I agree one should be using Joda-Time, I don't think the reason is Daylight Saving Time, not in this question. This question refers to dates without times. That means the [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class may used, without any time component, and therefore without any DST issues in play.

Answer (score 24):

Now that [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr310/index.html) has been included in the SDK of Java 8 and above, here's a more standard way of getting months difference of two date values:

```
public static final long getMonthsDifference(Date date1, Date date2) {
    YearMonth m1 = YearMonth.from(date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    YearMonth m2 = YearMonth.from(date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));

    return m1.until(m2, ChronoUnit.MONTHS) + 1;
}
```

This has a benefit of clearly spelling out the precision of the calculation and it is very easy to understand what is the intent of the calculation.

Comment: I get "The method from(TemporalAccessor) in the type YearMonth is not applicable for the arguments (Date)". Can not see why this is upvoted.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for pointing out my error @mkurz, Must have slipped through somehow. Any way, I fixed these type errors now and the snippet should be okay.

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone in determining a date. As written, UTC is used implicitly. Might be more appropriate to apply a `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime` to be passed to `YearMonth.from`.

Comment: True, time zone is being ignored. However, the impact of time zone is negligible given that fidelity of the desired output is number of months between two date values. In a pathological case the difference may have an effect but it is highly unlikely and in the case that the difference is important enough, it would be the responsibility of a developer to makes sure that time zones line up properly.

Comment: I'm getting  java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year by using this for converting the date to Instant.  The date where it fails is a current Date generated with java.util.Date() constructor. As java.util.Date class is very screwed, after dozens of years of programming in Java, I don't know the fix for this.

Comment: Okay, so, when I wrote this code first, I did not really check its behavior properly and it needs one more conversion to `ZonedDateTime` by calling `.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` (or whatever time zone you need to make calculation in - the time zone itself does not matter in this case at all, as long as both dates are translated to the same time zone). I'm going to fix the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Java 8 solution:

```
@Test
public void monthBetween() {

    LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2013, Month.APRIL, 1);
    LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 1);

    long monthBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(d1, d2);

    assertEquals(12, monthBetween);

}
```

Comment: cleaner solution than Roland Tepp's

Comment: Depends on what you want. Most readers will probably be happy with this one. It won’t give 2 months from Jan 29 to Feb 2 as the OP requested.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the above suggested answers I rolled my own which I added to my existing DateUtils class:

```
    public static Integer differenceInMonths(Date beginningDate, Date endingDate) {
        if (beginningDate == null || endingDate == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal1.setTime(beginningDate);
        Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal2.setTime(endingDate);
        return differenceInMonths(cal1, cal2);
    }

    private static Integer differenceInMonths(Calendar beginningDate, Calendar endingDate) {
        if (beginningDate == null || endingDate == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int m1 = beginningDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + beginningDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int m2 = endingDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + endingDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        return m2 - m1;
    }
```

And the associatiated unit tests:

```
    public void testDifferenceInMonths() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        assertEquals(12, DateUtils.differenceInMonths(sdf.parse("2014/03/22"), sdf.parse("2015/03/22")).intValue());

        assertEquals(11, DateUtils.differenceInMonths(sdf.parse("2014/01/01"), sdf.parse("2014/12/25")).intValue());

        assertEquals(88, DateUtils.differenceInMonths(sdf.parse("2014/03/22"), sdf.parse("2021/07/05")).intValue());

        assertEquals(6, DateUtils.differenceInMonths(sdf.parse("2014/01/22"), sdf.parse("2014/07/22")).intValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

using [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) would be like this (i compared how many months between today and 20/dec/2012)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime ;
import org.joda.time.Months;

DateTime x = new DateTime().withDate(2009,12,20); // doomsday lol

Months d = Months.monthsBetween( new DateTime(), x);
int monthsDiff = d.getMonths();
```

Result: 41 months (from july 6th 2009)

should be easy ? :)

ps: you can also convert your date using SimpleDateFormat 
like:

```
Date x = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("20/12/2009");
DateTime z = new DateTime(x);
```

If you don't want to use Joda (for whatever reason), you can convert your date to TimeStamp and then do the differences of milli seconds between both date and then calculate back to months. But I still prefer to use Joda time for the simplicity :)

Comment: If you're going to use Joda, you should use the Joda formatters as well, since the java.text stuff suffers from threading problems. I know in the above case it probably wouldn't apply, but it's a good practice :-)

Comment: hi Brian, can you give us example because I never know about that and willing to know more :) 
is it the substitute for SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( 
    YearMonth.from( LocalDate.of( 2009 , 1 , 29 ) ) , 
    YearMonth.from( LocalDate.of( 2009 , 2 , 2 ) )
)
```

## Time Zone

The [Answer by Roland Tepp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811261/642706) is close but ignores the crucial issue of time zone. Determining a month and date requires a time zone, as for any given moment **the date varies around the globe** by zone.

### `ZonedDateTime`

So his example of converting `java.util.Date` objects to `java.time.Instant` objects implicitly uses [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Values in either of those classes is always in UTC by definition. So you need to adjust those objects into the desired/intended time zone to be able to extract a meaningful date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = myJavaUtilDate1.toInstant().atZone( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = myJavaUtilDate2.toInstant().atZone( z );
```

### `YearMonth`

Since you want to know how many calendar months were touched by your date range rather than the number of 30-day chunks elapsed, convert to [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) objects.

```
YearMonth start = YearMonth.from( zdtStart );
YearMonth stop = YearMonth.from( zdtStop );
```

### `ChronoUnit`

Calculate months between by calling on [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
long monthsBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( start , stop );
```

> 1

### Half-Open

You desired a result of 2 but we get 1 here. The reason is that in date-time work the best practice is to define spans of time by the Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. I suggest you stick to this definition throughout your date-time work as doing so ultimately makes sense, eliminates confusing ambiguities, and makes your work easier to parse mentally and less error-prone. But if you insist on your definition, simply add `1` to the result assuming you have positive numbered results (meaning your spans of time go forward in time rather than backward).

### `LocalDate`

The original Question is not clear but may require date-only values rather than date-time values. If so, use the `LocalDate` class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2009 , 1 , 29 ) ; 
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2009 , 2 , 2 ) ;

long monthsBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( start ,  stop );
```

> 1

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Calendar or [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for this.

In Joda time you can use the Days.daysBetween() method. You can then calculate the months difference. You can also use DateTime.getMonthOfYear() and do a subtraction (for dates in the same year).

Comment: better using Months.monthsBetween than converting to Days and then rolling back to Months ;)

Comment: I didn't know about this method. It is definitely better.

Answer (score 2):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty cool library for Java Date and Time and can help you achieve what you want using [`Period`s](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of a month, but this is what we use:

```
int iMonths = 0;

Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);

Calendar cal2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(date2);

while (cal1.after(cal2)){
    cal2.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    iMonths++;
}

if (cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
            iMonths--;
        }


return iMonths;
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Wonder why you are still using the outmoded `Calendar` class? Several answers here use Joda-Time (also yesterday now) and the modern `java.time`, so really, you are doing no one a favour by sharing an outdated `Calendar` solution now, sorry.

Comment: @OleV.V. Joda-Time is *huge* and java.time is not available on Android below API 24.

Comment: Correction: `java.time` is available on lower Android API levels (below 26) though the ThreeTenABP, the Android edition of the backport. See [this questions: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

I had to write this implementation, becoz  I had custom defined periods, which i had to look for within two dates.
Here you can define you custom period and put the logic, for calculation.

Here TimePeriod is a POJO which has start, end, period start, period End

public class Monthly extends Period {

```
public int getPeriodCount(String startDate, String endDate, int scalar) {
    int cnt = getPeriods(startDate, endDate, scalar).size();        
    return cnt;
}

public List getPeriods(String startDate, String endDate, int scalar) {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    Calendar startCal = CalendarUtil.getCalendar(startDate);
    Calendar endCal =  CalendarUtil.getCalendar(endDate);

    while (startCal.compareTo(endCal) <= 0) {
        TimePeriod period = new TimePeriod();
        period.setStartDate(startCal.getTime());
        period.setPeriodStartDate(getPeriodStartDate((Calendar) startCal.clone()).getTime());
        Calendar periodEndCal = getPeriodEndDate((Calendar) startCal.clone(), scalar);
        period.setEndDate(endCal.before(periodEndCal) ? endCal.getTime()    : periodEndCal.getTime());
        period.setPeriodEndDate(periodEndCal.getTime());

        periodEndCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        startCal = periodEndCal;
        list.add(period);
    }

    return list;
}


private Calendar getPeriodStartDate(Calendar cal) {     
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE));        
    return cal;
}

private Calendar getPeriodEndDate(Calendar cal, int scalar) {

    while (scalar-- > 0) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        if (scalar > 0)
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);          
    }

    return cal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

it is  not the best anwer but you can use unixtimestamp
First you find the unixtime's of the dates 
then eject each other

Finally you should convert the unixtime(sum) to String

Comment: That would not return months difference. (Btw, this question is quite old and the options thoroughly discussed. Generally it is best to avoid resurrecting old threads unless the response contributes something significantly different over the previous answers.)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the classes `Java` Date and Calendar use the Month indices from `0-11`

```
January = 0
December = 1
```

Is recommended to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `java.util.Calendar` object:

```
private static Integer getMonthsBetweenDates(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Calendar todayDate = getCalendar(d1);
    Calendar pastDate = getCalendar(d2);

    int yearDiff = todayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - pastDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) < 11 && pastDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 31){ //if pastDate is smaller than 31/12
        yearDiff++;
    }

    int monthCount = 0;
    for (int year = 0 ; year < yearDiff ; year++){
        if (year == 0) {
            monthCount += 12 - pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        } else if (year == yearDiff - 1){ //last year
            if (todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) < pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
                monthCount += todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            } else if (todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) >= pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) && todayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < pastDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                monthCount += todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            } else if (todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) >= pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) && todayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= pastDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                monthCount += todayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            }
        }
        for (int months = 0 ; months < 12 ; months++){
            if (year > 0 && year < yearDiff -1){
                monthCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return monthCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate with full timedate

```
 public static Integer calculateMonthDiff(Date begining, Date end) throws Exception {

        if (begining.compareTo(end) > 0) {
            throw new Exception("Beginning date is greater than the ending date");
        }

        if (begining.compareTo(end) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        Calendar cEndCheckDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        cEndCheckDate.setTime(begining);
        int add = 0;
        while (true) {
            cEndCheckDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            add++;
            if (cEndCheckDate.getTime().compareTo(end) > 0) {
                return add - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A full code snippet for finding the difference of months between two date is as follows:

```
public String getContractMonth(String contractStart, String contractEnd) {
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String months = "0";
    try {
        Date startDate = dfDate.parse(contractStart);
        Date endDate = dfDate.parse(contractEnd);

        Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
        Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

        int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        months = diffMonth + "";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return months;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below logic will fetch you difference in months

```
(endCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)*12+endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))-(startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)*12+startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can by 30 days or by months :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int n = getNumbertOfMonth(LocalDate.parse("2016-08-31"),LocalDate.parse("2016-11-30"));
        System.out.println("number of month = "+n);

         n = getNumbertOfDays(LocalDate.parse("2016-08-31"),LocalDate.parse("2016-11-30"));
        System.out.println("number of days = "+n);
        System.out.println("number of 30 days = "+n/30);
    }
        static int getNumbertOfMonth(LocalDate dateDebut, LocalDate dateFin) {

        LocalDate start = dateDebut;
        LocalDate end = dateFin;
        int count = 0 ;
        List<String> lTotalDates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
            count++;
            start =  start.plusMonths(1);
        }
        return count;
    }

    static int getNumbertOfDays(LocalDate dateDebut, LocalDate dateFin) {

        LocalDate start = dateDebut;
        LocalDate end = dateFin;
        int count = 0 ;
        List<String> lTotalDates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
            count++;
            start =  start.plusDays(1);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long monthsBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(LocalDate.parse("2016-01-29").minusMonths(1),
            LocalDate.parse("2016-02-02").plusMonths(1));
```

1. 2016-01-29 to 2016-01-02  = months 1
2. 2016-02-29 to 2016-02-02  = months 1
3. 2016-03-29 to 2016-05-02  = months 5

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete implementation for monthDiff in java without iterations. It returns the number of **full** month between two dates. If you want to include the number of incomplete month in the result (as in the initial question), you have to zero out the day, hours, minutes, seconds and millisecondes of the two dates before calling the method, or you could change the method to not compare days, hours, minutes etc.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
...
public static int monthDiff(Date d1, Date d2) {
    int monthDiff;

    Calendar c1, c2;
    int M1, M2, y1, y2, t1, t2, h1, h2, m1, m2, s1, s2, ms1, ms2;

    c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);

    c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(d2);

    M1 = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    M2 = c2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    y1 = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    y2 = c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    t1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    t2 = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if(M2 < M1) { 
        M2 += 12;
        y2--;
    }

    monthDiff = 12*(y2 - y1) + M2 - M1;

    if(t2 < t1)
        monthDiff --; // not a full month
    else if(t2 == t1) { // perhaps a full month, we have to look into the details
        h1 = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        h2 = c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if(h2 < h1)
            monthDiff--; // not a full month
        else if(h2 == h1) { // go deeper
            m1 = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            m2 = c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if(m2 < m1) // not a full month
                monthDiff--;
            else if(m2 == m1) { // look deeper
                s1 = c1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                s2 = c2.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                if(s2 < s1)
                    monthDiff--; // on enleve l'age de mon hamster
                else if(s2 == s1) { 
                    ms1 = c1.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                    ms2 = c2.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                    if(ms2 < ms1)
                        monthDiff--;
                    // else // it's a full month yeah
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return monthDiff;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Thanks I'am aware of this but there are still some people out there which are stuck to older JDK's.

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is available for Java 6 and Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library. So there is no need to ever again touch those bloody awful old date-time classes.

Comment: so much code for just a single math operation... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074578/4211173

Answer (score 0):

You can use Period class in java

```
    Period.between(
            firstYearMonth.atDay(1),
            secondYearMonth.atDay(1)
    ).getMonths();
```

This will return an integer aka month difference between 2 year month.

Answer (score -1):

So many answers with long code when you can just do it with 1 line and some math:

```
LocalDate from = yourdate;
LocalDate to = yourotherdate;

int difference = to.getMonthValue() - from.getMonthValue()) + ((to.getYear() - from.getYear()) * 12) + 1;
```

Comment: This is already in the two top-voted answers. Some of the other answers have it even simpler — one line leaving the math to a proven library method. Using `LocalDate` is a good idea for dates.

Comment: This does not add anything new to already presented answers. Removing line breaks does not make it either better or different from other similar answers. In fact it will most likely hurt readability.