# How to calculate difference ONLY in months using Java's Joda API

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am writing a program that is supposed to just calculate the months between 2 given dates and return the value to the program. For instance, if I have to calculate the number of months between 1 April and 30 June (which is a quarter, 3 months), and I use the following code:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 4, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 6, 30);

    Months mt = Months.monthsBetween(start, end);
    int monthDiff = mt.getMonths();
```

Using this, I am still getting "2" as the number of months, whereas it is actually "3" months. This is an example of what I want. I am only calculating the number of months (i.e. from 1st of the start month t the last date of the end month) and I dont need additional analysis like days, weeks, hours, etc. How do I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't wait to read the answer from Jon Skeet, the Stackoverflow and Date API expert ;)

Comment: I believe the Yoda time answer is correct. From april 1st to (but not including) june 30th would be _almost_ 3 months. I think both dates have the same time (00:00) and thus june 30th isn't really included in the range.

Comment: @extraneon - Thats right. The Period displayed is 2 months, 4 weeks and 1 day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 4, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 6, 30);
Period p = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.months().withDaysRemoved());
int months = p.getMonths() + 1;
```

You need the `withDaysRemoved()` part to ensure that adding one to the number of months works. Otherwise two dates such as `2011-04-15` and `2011-06-14` would still result in the answer being `2`

Comment: This seems to be working fine. I will do some more testing and check

Comment: This is not working. For instance, it fails for 2015-06-10 and 2015-07-01 ("months" ends up with 1 instead of 2). The correct solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086432/1369016

Answer (score 3):

Why do you expect the answer to be `3 months`? The precise answer is *two months and a little bit*, which then results in the *two months* you are getting.

If you want the *number of months that are “touched” by this interval*, this is a completely different question. <strike>Just add 1 to the result of the difference.</strike>

Comment: The problem there is that depending on the day provided, adding one to month might not work.

Comment: I didn't mean to add one month to a date, but to add 1 to the `monthDiff` variable in the question.

Comment: I know. If the dates were 2011-04-15 and 2011-06-14, that would fail because getMonths() would return 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Months mt = Months.monthsBetween(
    start.monthOfYear().roundFloorCopy(), 
    end.monthOfYear().roundCeilingCopy()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Joda algorithm counted correctly difference between this two dates. This pseudo-code will be the easiest way to explain how it works:

```
// (1)
monthsBetween(2011.6.14, 2011.4.15) = 1
monthsBetween(2011.6.15, 2011.4.15) = 2
// (2)
monthsBetween(2011.6.30, 2011.4.1) = 2
monthsBetween(2011.7.1,  2011.4.1) = 3
```

To do what you want you need to "improve" joda algorithm:

- Count distance between two dates (use normal monthsBetween)
- If you have specific situation: the last day of month in one date and the 1st day of month in second date, add +1 to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Let `y1` and `m1` be the year and month of the start date, 
and `y2` and `m2` be the year and month of the end date. 
Then the number of months between
start and end, including the months of the start and end dates is

```
(y2 - y1) * 12 + (m2 - m1) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 4, 1);
        DateTime end = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 2, 1);
        Period p = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.months().withDaysRemoved());
        int months = p.getMonths();
        System.out.println(months);


wrong output in this case
```