# MONTHS_BETWEEN function does not give the expected result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using MONTHS_BETWEEN function to get the difference between 2 dates , but the result is not 100% correct i think this function mines 1 day . 
i tried  this SQL

```
 SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20170630','YYYYMMDD'),
   TO_DATE('20170501','YYYYMMDD') ) "Months"
    FROM DUAL;
```

here in this case it should return `2` but the result is `1.93548387096774` 
So, Any help ?? or is there any way to add 1 more day to date??

Comment: If you want to add 1 more day to date you can use `DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) '

Comment: See similar Questions: [*Months between not returning correct value*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46070595/642706) & [*Analog of ORACLE function MONTHS_BETWEEN in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9100543/642706)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT ROUND( MONTHS_BETWEEN(
  TO_DATE('20170630','YYYYMMDD'), 
  TO_DATE('20170501','YYYYMMDD'))) 
"Months" FROM DUAL;
```

`MONTHS_BETWEEN` returns decimal result if days are different and they are not both specify the last day of the month. For more info see http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/months_between

Comment: IT will not work round here

Comment: It works in Oracle emulator here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d890/3

Comment: You get sqlfiddle to work? It always fails when I try. Pretty much given up on that and use this one instead for Oracle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ec153e296b0880c80515b8e50471ec0d

Comment: Works as well: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e62865daa3b3e0d27d27753a37cee925

Comment: Guess the problem is not that if it works or not. `ROUND` will give you result 2 even from `11th May` to `30th June` which is not what OP wants. Question is more specific to `months_between` that why from `1st May` to `30th June` it is not giving `2` and to get it , you should add 1 day to last_date.

Answer (score 0):

Months between will give you a decimal value with respect to a whole month. So from `1st Jan` to `1st Feb`, you will get `1`. But from `1st Jan` to `31st Jan` you will not get exact `1`. It will be `0.9...`.  Similarly from `31st Jan` to `28th Feb` (non leap year) you will get 1.

So you will get `2` from `1st May` to `1st July` OR from `30th April` to `30th June`,

From `1st May` to `30th June`, you will never get exact 2.

If you want exact `2`, then either add `1` day to greater date or subtract 1 day from start_date.

<kbd>**[`DBFiddle Demo`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34963101080968bfa9f7aacd7a11a343)**</kbd>