# Months between not returning correct value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select MOD (RUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('28-Mar-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
 TO_DATE ('28-Feb-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))), 12) Months from dual
```

Why is this function returning 1 month even if not completed the month? Its supposed to be 0

Comment: *"ORACLE MOTHSBETWEEN"* Hate when that happens. Endless source of bugs. ;-)

Comment: Why do you think there is not a month between them? 1st Feb to 1st Mar would be one month difference so why is 28th Feb to 28th Mar not also a month difference?

Comment: See similar Question: [*Analog of ORACLE function MONTHS_BETWEEN in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9100543/642706)

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong. `MONTHS_BETWEEN` treats the time span from `date '2017-02-28'` to `date '2017-03-28'` as exactly one month (same day in two adjacent months). This can be read in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

> MONTHS_BETWEEN returns number of months between dates date1 and date2. If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. If date1 is earlier than date2, then the result is negative. If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last days of months, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2.

One date is bigger than the other so you get a positive or negative number (i.e. not zero) depending on which is first and which is second parameter, and as the days equal, the result will be an integer. That is 1 or -1 for adjacent months.

---

Month calculation is a strange thing anyway, as a month is not a defined time span. You seem to have a certain definition in mind, which simply is different from how `MONTHS_BETWEEN` defines it. Nothing wrong about that. I would agree with `MONTHS_BETWEEN` in this case; from Feb 28 to Mar 28 is "exactly" one month. If you want different rules, then apply your own math :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is working to its [documented specification](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669):

> `MONTHS_BETWEEN` returns number of months between dates `date1` and `date2`.
>   The month and the last day of the month are defined by the parameter
>   `NLS_CALENDAR`. If `date1` is later than `date2`, then the result is
>   positive. If `date1` is earlier than `date2`, then the result is negative.
>   If `date1` and `date2` are either the same days of the month or both last
>   days of months, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle
>   Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a
>   31-day month and considers the difference in time components `date1` and
>   `date2`.

If you have requirements that are different to this then you will need to write your own function.