# Scala: Difference between 2 dates in number of months

Tags: java, scala, java-time

I have two `String` variables containing values `"201703"` and `"201506"` respectively i.e. the values are of the format `"yyyyMM"` but variables of type `String`. I want to find out the difference between those two dates in number months using Scala and JDK 8.

Example inputs:

```
val x = "201506"
val y = "201703"
```

Desired output:

```
21
```

Comment: It’s sort of a duplicate of [Java Date month difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086396/java-date-month-difference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done easily with Java Time.

```
  import java.time.YearMonth
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit._

  val date1 = "201506"
  val date2 = "201703"

  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")

  val ym1 = YearMonth.parse(date1, formatter)
  val ym2 = YearMonth.parse(date2, formatter)

  val months = ym1.until(ym2, MONTHS)
```

Comment: Thank yo so much. Worked like a dream !!