# Get the number of months beetween a date and today in JAVA

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, monthcalendar

I'm trying to get the number of months between a given date in a String format ("2019-05-31"), sent as a parameter, and today : 2020-07-13. In this example it would be 13 month.

I want to put the answer in an int variable.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Niroshan The terrible `Date` classes both were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.

Comment: This doesn’t seem well researched? There are some similar questions, for example [Java Date month difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086396/java-date-month-difference). [This answer by Kuchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147750/5772882) wold probably have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 1.8:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-05-31");
int months = (int) Period.between(myDate,today).toTotalMonths();
System.out.println(months); // output: 13
```

Comment: wow thank you so much...didn't know it was so simple :D

Comment: While it’s very unlikely for the result not to fit into an `int`, I find it best to scheck the assumption that it does. Use [`Math.toIntExact(Period.between(myDate,today).toTotalMonths())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)).

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

Use *java.time* classes.

The `Period::toTotalMonths` method returns a `long` for the number of months elapsed along the entire span of time.

You asked for an `int` rather than a `long`. Rather than cast that `long` to your desired `int`, call `Math.toIntExact`. This method throws an exception if the resulting narrowing from the cast overflows.

```java
int months =
    Math.toIntExact(
        Period.between
        (
            LocalDate.parse( "2019-05-31" ) ,
            LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
        )
        .toTotalMonths()
    )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DateUtil{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = "2019-05-31";
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        long diff = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(localDate, now);

        System.out.println(diff);

    }
}
```

Comment: No need to define a custom formatting pattern for standard ISO 8601 format. Built-in.